# Dialog Box is called more than once in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have tried the code below. The Problem I am facing is that, whenever F2 key is pressed the Dialog Box open twice. But it works fine when I open the dialog box by clicking on Label "Forgot Password". Please help me out.

```
package dialogdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author vikassingh
 */
public class DialogDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox beforeButtonBox = new HBox();
        HBox.setHgrow(beforeButtonBox, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox hboxspace3 = new HBox();
        HBox.setHgrow(hboxspace3, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Label forgotPasswodKeycode = new Label("F2");
        forgotPasswodKeycode.setStyle(" -fx-text-fill: #000 ; -fx-font-size: 20;  -fx-underline: true; -fx-font-weight: bold ;");
        Label forgotPasswod = new Label(" Forgot Password?");
        forgotPasswod.setStyle(" -fx-text-fill: #000 ; -fx-font-size: 20; -fx-font-weight: bold ;");
        beforeButtonBox.getChildren().addAll(forgotPasswodKeycode, forgotPasswod);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(beforeButtonBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Dialog Demo!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        root.requestFocus();

        //  Key listener 
        root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB || event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                    // Do Something
                    event.consume();
                } else {
                    try {
                        event.consume();
                        keyAction(event.getCode().toString(), root, primaryStage);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DialogDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        forgotPasswod.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                forgotPassword();
            }
        });
        // END Listner
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // F1 & Esc Key Action
    public void keyAction(String keyCode, StackPane root, Stage rootStage) throws Exception {
        if (keyCode.equalsIgnoreCase("F2")) {
            forgotPassword();
        }
    }
    // End F1 & Esc Key Action

    // Forgot Password
    public void forgotPassword() {
        Dialog<List<String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        DialogPane dialogPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
        dialog.setTitle("Forgoods");
        dialog.setHeaderText(null);
        dialog.setGraphic(null);
        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        ButtonType cancleButtonType = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, cancleButtonType);

        // VBox
        VBox alertVBox = new VBox();
        VBox.setVgrow(alertVBox, Priority.ALWAYS);
        alertVBox.setPrefWidth(400.0);
        alertVBox.setSpacing(10);

        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton("select first");
        button1.setToggleGroup(group);
        button1.setUserData("A");
        button1.setSelected(true);
        RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton("select second");
        button2.setToggleGroup(group);
        button2.setUserData("B");

        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
                if (group.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                    System.out.println(group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        alertVBox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);
        // END VBox

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(alertVBox);
        // Request focus on the username field by default.
        Platform.runLater(() -> dialogPane.lookupButton(okButtonType).requestFocus());

        List<String> databaseFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == okButtonType) {
                return databaseFiles; // return Something
            }
            return null;
        });
        Optional<List<String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            // Do Something
        } else {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
    // END Forgot Password

}
```

Comment: I have check your code  dialog box open one time only.which jdk you have use. i have run in your code in jdk1.8.0_45 please check this version in your   code

Comment: @ReeganMiranda : For windows jdk1.8.0_45 its working fine. But for Mac jdk-8u51-nb-8_0_2-macosx-x64 its not working..!!

Comment: ohh.. ok i dno't have mac os

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is triggered multiple times, if the key is pressed long enough.

You could use the `KEY_RELEASED` event, which should trigger only once:

```
root.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    ...
});
```

alternatively you could set a `boolean` that prevents the dialog to be opened more than once (code a bit simplified):

```
    root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        private boolean dialogOpen = false;

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (!dialogOpen) {
                dialogOpen = true;

                Dialog dialog = ...;
                dialog.showAndWait();

                dialogOpen = false;
            }
        }

    });
```

That

Comment: I have tried setOnKeyReleased, its working fine for Dialog box. But by using setOnKeyReleased the working of other scenes of my application is effected. Is there any other way to achieve this by using setOnKeyPress only..???